# How to convert & to &amp; using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have small requirement, I'm going to upload some csv file data and data should be displayed in text area , it is working fine.
But if data have "&" characted it should converts to '&' .
    eg:`&101,&abc,&smith,&1000 should be displayed to &amp;101,&amp;abc,&amp;smith,&amp1000.`

Please share me some idea.

```
I tried with following code
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#saveImgID").click(function(){
    var xmlStart =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Rowsets>";
    var xmlEnd = "</Rowset></Rowsets>";
    var xml;
    var lines = $('#fileContent1').val().split(/\n/);
    var texts = []
    for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
        texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
      }
    }
    xml = xmlStart + "<Rowset>";
    for (var i=0; i < texts.length; i++) {         
      xml += "<Row><Line>"+texts[i]+"</Line></Row>";
    }
    xml += xmlEnd;
    alert(xml);
  });     
});
```

and Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hy91m3tr/7/)

Comment: If it's going to be submitted, why not just URL encode with `encodeURIComponent` instead. That won't give you `&amp;`, but it will be valid

Comment: You can use the string's `replace()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `replace()`.

```
xml += "<Row><Line>"+texts[i].replace(/&/g, '&amp;')+"</Line></Row>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery hack.

```
var data = "&101,&abc,&smith,&1000";
var result = $('<div/>').text(data).html();
console.log(result);
```

For more details read this CMS answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/17447

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
$(".selectBorder").html($(".selectBorder").html().replace(/&/g, '&amp;'))
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hy91m3tr/8/)